# Side effects of passing temporary as const T& and binding to class reference

Tags: c++, reference, temporary

Let's say I've a struct definition and some function like this:

```cpp
struct A{
 const std::string& _s;
 A(const std::string& s):_s(s){}
 //A(const std::string s): _s(s){}
};
 int main(void){
    A a("E");
    std::cout << a._s << '\n';
}
```

This doesn't error or warn at all by default, you can get it to throw an error at runtime by compiling with asan. From my understanding what happens is, the temporary `"E` to which `s` is bound to dies at the end of first expression, meaning `A a("E")` and therefore the reference in the class gets invalidated after that. So at the `cout <<` point we are accessing a dangling reference.

At compile time, if we replace the first constructor with the 2nd, a warning is generated, that it's binding the reference to the temporary `s` and so now accessing `s` after the `A a("E")` expression is over is also UB.

Assuming the two cases are correct, is there ever a case where

```cpp
auto x= A("E")._s
```

would be UB? And if so, when?

Comment: No.   In `auto x = A("E")._s`  the temporary `std::string` constructed to be passed to the constructor of `A` is guaranteed to exist until the end of the statement.   So `x` will have type `std::string` and it will be initialised using a reference to the temporary, while that temporary still exists.

Comment: @Peter So regardless of if I pass the string  temporary as `const std::string&` or by value, as ```std::string``` the copy constructor would be called regardless. (On a similar note, something like auto& x= A("E)._s; would be UB in both cases, I assume?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [c++17 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) §15.2 point 6.9 says

> - temporary object bound to a reference parameter in a function call (8.5.1.2) persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the call

So you are good. No UB here `auto x= A("E")._s`.

The other issues you have described well yourself. After construction accessing the member will be UB.

You can, however, extend the lifetime of a temporary object by binding it to a local const-reference like so:

```
struct A {
   const std::string& _s;
   A(const std::string& s) : _s(s) {}    
};

int main(void) {
   const std::string& e = "E";
   A a(e);
   std::cout << a._s << '\n';
}
```

which would not be UB, but I would not use it like this.

Comment: Thank you. I assume my understanding of the initial two cases being UB are correct also, right? (regarding binding to the const&)

Comment: Yes, they are correct. Sorry, misunderstood you before completely.

Comment: I added another example where a temporary objects life time is extended. Just in case you are interested.

Comment: I see, thank you. It makes sense! And also, regarding my initial post,  would  `auto& x= A("E)._s`  not be UB in any case?

Comment: @pol `x` would immediately become a dangling reference since the temporary that `_s` refers to is destroyed

Comment: As far as I understand this will not work as this will be deduced to be const std::string& x and extending the lifetime of the object A but not of the passed "E". So It will be dangling and be UB. Not 100% sure though t.b.h.

Comment: In your post your wrote auto ``x= A("E)._s`` and not ``auto& x= A("E)._s``. This auto will be deduced to std::string and hence be a copy. Whereas in auto& x= A("E)._s it will be deduced to const std::string&.

Comment: yeah, i wanted to make sure about `auto&` as well! my initial question was about `auto` alone

Answer (score 1):

Here's some simple testing code which prints exactly when the lifetimes of various objects start and stop:

```cpp
struct loud {
    loud(const char*) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__  << '\n'; }
    loud(const loud&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__  << '\n'; }
    ~loud() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__  << '\n'; }
};

struct A {
    const loud& _s;
    // A(const loud& s) : _s(s) {}
    A(loud s) : _s(s) {}
};

int main() {
    loud x = A("E")._s;
}
```

Which outputs:

```cpp
loud::loud(const char *)
loud::loud(const loud &)
loud::~loud()
loud::~loud()
```

And as you can see, the `loud` object constructed with `"E"` is not destroyed before it is copied from.

---

In both cases, a temporary object is created and is bound to either `const loud& s` or `loud s`, the argument of the constructor. All temporary objects are destroyed at the end of the full-expression that contains them, so they will be alive for the entirety of `A("E")._s`, so can be copied from.

This also means that the following would not work since the temporaries are created in a different full-expression:

```
// The following is a hard compile time error on clang, but compiles on gcc
struct A {
    const loud& _s;
    A(loud s) : _s(s) {}
    A(const char* s) : _s(s)  /* Temporary `loud` used to initialize `_s` is destroyed here */ {}
};

// But this compiles
struct A {
    const loud& _s;
    A(loud s) : _s(s) {}
    A(const char* s) : A(loud(s))  /* Temporary materialized from `loud(s)` is destroyed here */ {}
};
```

The temporary object is destroyed before the `{` of the constructor body (and before the constructors of any subsequent data members if there were any), so it is already destroyed before the `.` in `A("E")._s`.

In both of these cases, the following is output with the same `main` function:

```cpp
loud::loud(const char *)
loud::~loud()
loud::loud(const loud &)
loud::~loud()
```

(Where the object is used after it is destroyed, which would be UB if the copy constructor tried to access any data members on the object like if it was a `std::string`)

Comment: Great answer. Interestingly, I can get g++ to merely warn about this with `-Wextra`